# A simple exercise with sequence

Tags: c++

I am new to this and I need help with an exercise, which seems to be very simple but I was thinking for hours.

I have a sequence of integers, and I have to return an ordered sequence from least to greatest. whose elements have the same difference. Example: {1,4,5,6,7,10} -> {4,5,6,7}

Comment: you mean that you need to calculate differences between every number and its previous and if all was the same return them?

Comment: exactly.
sorry if this is very simple

Comment: A simple solution would be to first sort the sequence if it isn't sorted. After that, you can iterate through the now ordered sequence and maintain the difference between each number you iterated through. If the difference remains the same, you just keep  the pointer and the corresponding length. Repeat this process, eventually you will get one or more such pointers and lengths representing all subsequences with equal differences between elements.

Comment: Also I assumed all elements are adjacent to each other. Does it take sequence like {1,4,7,10} from the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible algorithm:

Store your *N* integers in a `vector<int>` and sort it. Then for every integer *K<sub>i</sub>* for *i*=2 to *i=n* check if *K<sub>i</sub>* - *K<sub>i-1</sub>* equals *K<sub>i-1</sub> - K<sub>i-2</sub>*.

Note that in C++, indices start from 0, not 1, so adapt the above accordingly (your *i* will be from 1 to *n-1* instead of 2 to *n*.

I'm not going to write the code for you though, that's your homework.